# problem in sending a SOAP request

Tags: android, http, soap, request

I am using the follwing code to send SOAP request.

```
 String str = new StringBuilder("POST /WrenchTelLink/WrenchENTService.asmx HTTP/1.1\n")
              .append("Host: 59.160.183.14\n")
              .append("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\n")
              .append("Content-Length: LLLLLL\n")
              .append("SOAPAction: \"http://WrenchGlobal/GetToDoList\"\n ")
              .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>")
              .append("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-      
               instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
               xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n")
              .append("<soap:Body>\n")
              .append("<GetToDoList xmlns=\"http://WrenchGlobal/\">\n")
              .append("<viPeriod>IIIIII</viPeriod>\n")
              .append("<vsUserID>SSSSSS</vsUserID>\n")
              .append("</GetToDoList>\n")
              .append("</soap:Body>\n")
              .append("</soap:Envelope>\n").toString();
 String temp = str.replaceAll("LLLLLL",Integer.toString(str.length()))
   .replaceAll("SSSSSS",ph).replaceAll("IIIIII",Integer.toString(period));
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

  try
   {
      StringEntity se = new StringEntity(temp,HTTP.UTF_8);

      se.setContentType("text/xml");  
      httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");

      httppost.setEntity(se);  
      BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse)httpclient.execute(httppost);

      if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString()!="") 
         Toast.makeText(TelLinkActivity.this, httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString()
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      else
          Toast.makeText(TelLinkActivity.this,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Its not showing any of the TOAST messages. I am not getting what i am supposed understand from this. Its not working at all. Could anyone tell me if there is something wrong with the code..?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  If so, try posting those.  Also, I started using a library called ksoap2 to do my SOAP requests, which I found to be very handy.  http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Comment: I am not getting any error, but its just not showing any TOAST message. How to use ksoap2 in an application?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/167-using-ksoap2-for-android-soap-web-service   Or Google "android ksoap" and you'll find quite a few articles

Comment: Also, to debug your original issue, have you ran the code in debug and stepped through it?  I'm guessing that it's failing in the first few lines of your try-catch block before it gets to the if-else to display the toast messages.

Comment: ya exactly. I have not tried what you said. I will try it once and get back here.

Comment: i am not getting how to use ksoap2 in my application, can you please tell me..?

Comment: @hooked82 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2169/discussion-between-kishan-and-hooked82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show Toast in ui thread, by runOnUiThread for example

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(TelLinkActivity.this,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to convey.

Comment: the question is not about displaying one of the toast messages, but it is to find out whats wrong with the code. I dont think what you said is gonna make some difference. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: you should get any result, just debug, or enable logging, code works, I know it ^_^